# WKExtendedRuntimeSession hit internal error: 'startSession cannot be called on a scheduled session'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a background session for my app, but when trying to start the session by a press of a button, I'm getting following error:

```
WKExtendedRuntimeSession hit internal error. Error Domain=com.apple.CarouselServices.SessionErrorDomain Code=17 "startSession cannot be called on a scheduled session" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=startSession cannot be called on a scheduled session}
```

Any idea why ? This is my code. I tried googling the error but I cab't find a solution anywhere. For background session I have used the background modes capability and I have selected the smart alarm session type (no other selections):

```
import SwiftUI

final class ExtendedRunTimeService {
    
    private var session: WKExtendedRuntimeSession?
    
    func start() {
        guard session?.state != .running else { return }
        if nil == session || session?.state == .invalid {
            session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
        }
        print("session started")
        session?.start()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        session?.invalidate()
    }
    
}
```

And I'm starting it through:

```
import Combine

final class ClockDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var motionValues = MotionValues()
    @Published var healthValues = HealthValues()
    
    var motionService = MotionService()
    var healthService = HealthService()
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    var backGroundService = ExtendedRunTimeService()
    
    init() {
        motionService.$motionValues
            .combineLatest(healthService.$healthValues)
            .sink(receiveValue: {
                self.motionValues = $0
                self.healthValues = $1
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func startUpdates() {
        backGroundService.start()
        motionService.startMotionUpdates()
        healthService.fetchHeartRateData(quantityTypeIdentifier: .heartRate)
    }
    
    func stopUpdates() {
        backGroundService.stop()
        motionService.stopMotionUpdates()
        healthService.stopFetchingHeartRateData()
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so figured it out. For a smart alarm I should used the method start(at: ) requiring a future date for the session to start.

```
session?.start(at: Date())
```